# Half Wave Rectifier with Capacitive Filter

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, diodes, rectifier

[image: problem]

This is an example problem in my workbook. Please can someone explain me the working of the circuit and how is this formula derived.

I got 1 more solution to the same problem.

[image: ssolution2]

Comment: Where are you stuck? I would prefer to see the formula in terms of tcyc = 1/f.

Comment: @Sephro Sir, how we get this formula ? And as RC >>T, diode current should be 0 then.

Comment: Consider the capacitor only charges to Vm instantaneously at the positive peaks of the input voltage and the diode does not conduct otherwise. That is an approximation. The purpose of the first part of the formula is to determine the average DC voltage.

Comment: Try to draw the diode current i(t). Then a simple mathematical average over the cycle should yield the average diode current.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I got what you were trying to say. Please check my edited question and tell me which one is correct.

Comment: @Nikhil Look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584337/finding-the-current-trough-an-ideal-diode-mistake-in-given-answer I think your workbook is right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your workbook is wrong with that formula. They have used the full wave rectifier formula. For HWR, It has to be :

$$V_{dc} = V_m - I_{dc}/2fC$$

Your derivation is correct.

[image]
From the above waveform,

$$V_{dc} = V_m - V_{rpp}/2$$ from ripple waveform, the amount of charge stored by the capacitor = The charge lost by it in time T seconds. i.e.,
$$C V_{rpp}= I_{dc}T$$

which gives, $$V_{rpp} = I_{dc}/fC$$
Therefore,

$$V_{dc} = V_m - I_{dc}/2fC$$

Comment: His derivation of average load current is correct, however his diode current is not.

Comment: Thanks @MITU RAJ and Bruce Abbott for answering. I applied your formula and got Idc=0.0975mA. Will this also be the diode current? I am really confused with diode current calculation.

Comment: Not really cz there's a small current flow through capacitor. That's why the question asks "approximately". So you may say so.

Comment: But RC>>T. So in steady state, most of the time discharging will take place while only for a short duration charging will happen (when diode conducts). I am trying to say that diode current should have been negligible compared to capacitor current

Comment: Since voltage across the load = voltage across capacitor, and its not pure dc, Cdv/dt current always exist through cap. So it adds up with the current through load at the node, to get the total current coming through diode. Since dv/dt is very small here, you can neglect it. After all GATE questions are full of assumptions :D

Comment: @MITURAJ Thanks for explaining. These assumptions really frustating.

Comment: @MITURAJ Look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584337/finding-the-current-trough-an-ideal-diode-mistake-in-given-answer I think that you're wrong!

Comment: I am not really into such complex mathematics you have presented there. But the relation I derived here for Idc and Vdc is confirmed in all electronics textbooks. You can refer to Mottorshead's electronics devices and circuit text. Besides I never claimed Idc is the EXACT current through Diode because a small capacitor current is also there. But question asks for "APPROXIMATELY". Hence Idc itself is the answer they are expecting here. After all this question is from a competitive exam in which you have only 1 minute to answer.

Comment: Maybe yours is the most accurate formula. But if you refer to electronics textbooks, lotta approximations are taken for every formula they derive. Even this standard formula which is derived in texbooks, uses a triangular approximation of the smooth ripple wave. Well, all this to make calculations simple.

Comment: @MITURAJ But the OP claims that the average current trough the diode is \$0.29\$ A but that is not true. It is the \$0.09\$ A that is presented in the OP's textbook!

Comment: The answer is approx. 0.097 Amp, as per the formula I derived here. Workbook says 0.09 Amps. That slight mistake is because they took 4fc in the denominator for Vdc expression. While 2fc is the correct one. That's what I meant by "workbook is wrong". The OP has derived it to be 0.097 Amps at one stage. That derivation is correct. But his final answer 0.29 A is wrong anyway.

Comment: @MITURAJ According to my formula the average current trough the diode is \$\approx0.080002533\$ A